# Can't fetch data from db with node and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I am coding a website with angular 8 and node.js.

I have used the same logic to fetch user info previously but this time I can't get it to work (even if I think everything should be fine and was triple checked).

Here is what I do:

Angular service:

```
return this.http.get<EnterViewActivateReturn>(this.serviceURL + email, option).pipe(
  catchError((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    return throwError('error');
  }),
);
```

`console.log(email) is correct`

Node back:

```
const sql = "SELECT email, key FROM user WHERE email = ?";
  const query = db.format(sql, [req.params.email]);
  db.query(query, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'User not found',
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Successfully fetched user infos',
        email: response[0].email,
        key: response[0].key
      });
    }
```

'user' db structure:

[image]

The route is also fine and the GET method goes through just fine..
I keep on getting a `User not found` response tho, even if the same logic works in another component.

How can I debug this? / What is the issue here?

Tell me if you need more informations! Thank you

**EDIT: Problem solved in the comments, there was a parse error in my sql request. Don't forget to `console.log(err)` your backend and check the server console for logs!**

Comment: is the data being returned using POSTman?

Comment: @AmmarHussain no it 's just a callback

Comment: The simplest way to debug this would be to add `console.error(err)` before sending error-response (inside `if (err) {...}`)

Comment: @IhorSakaylyuk Thanks for your reply, I tried adding `console.error(err)` inside the `if` but nothing is displayed in the console

Comment: Are you checking nodejs console or browser dev-tools console? Because the error should appear in the nodejs console

Comment: Oh! Your absolutely right, I was never checking the server console where the error was displayed. I have a parse error! Thank you so much